# Match a word followed by any digit with exception

Tags: regex, exception

Concretly, I must match the word `cat` followed by any digit(s), but not match if the digits is `12`.

```
cat3   YES
cat12  NO
cat43  YES
cat18  YES
rel97  NO
cat12  NO
cat    NO
cat36  YES
cat14  YES
cat12  NO
cat123 YES
```

The 'best' regex I can build for now is `cat\d+`, which match all I want but also match `cat12`, matches that I want to exclude.

https://regex101.com/r/lNY38M/1

Is it possible to express an exception when using regex matching?

Comment: If supported, use a negative lookahead `\bcat(?!12)\d+` https://regex101.com/r/9TvIqI/1 or if you do want to match cat121, use `\bcat(?!12\b)\d+`

Comment: @Thefourthbird. Very interesting, thank you. But this also exclude `cat123`, which should match.

Comment: Then use `\bcat(?!12\b)\d+` https://regex101.com/r/GtaP7Q/1

Comment: @Thefourthbird. Looks like exactly what I was looking for. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want to match `cat12` but do want to match `cat123`, you can use a negative lookahead assering not 12 followed by a word boundary:

```
\bcat(?!12\b)\d+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GtaP7Q/1)

If lookarounds are not supported, you could also match a digit followed by either an optional digit `0` `1` `3` `4` `5` `6` `7` `8` `9` or match 3 or more digits.

```
\bcat(?:\d[013-9]?|\d{3,})\b
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/qPkYN6/1)